# dimension of range of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

It's well-know that if $\mathbf{X}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ then dim(range($\mathbf{X}\theta$))=rank$(\mathbf{X})$ for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^k.$

1) I was wondering to know dim(range($\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}$)) for $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$. I guess that the answer is rank$(\mathbf{X}).d$

Because we can expand the multiplication as sum of $k$ parts which are independent of each other and each part has dimension of $d$. Note that we exploit this fact that elements of matrix $A$ can be any arbitrary numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

2) My main question is about the comparison between dim(range($\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$)) for $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$ and $\mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{R}^{d \times p}$ as well as dim(range($\mathbf{X}\mathbf{M}$)) for $\mathbf{M}\in \mathbb{R}^{k \times p}$.

I think that dim(range($\mathbf{X}\mathbf{M}$))=rank$(\mathbf{X}).p$ but dim(range($\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$))$<$rank$(\mathbf{X}).p$ Since rank($\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$)$<$min(k,d,p)

Comment: Aha, do I understand it right that you are talking about dim(range(X*theta)) as the dim(range(...)) of this as a function of all theta in R^k? And for the others you mean dim(range(...)) of functions in entries of A, A and B, M respectively? So the resulting image space is a subset of R^k vs. the space of n x d matrices for XA ?

Comment: At first I thought this might be a question generated by a text-generation neural network, trained on SE questions or something. I totally didn't get it

Comment: If that's what you mean, your guess in 1) is right, just re-write the matrix-matrix product as matrix-vector product (stack the columns of A to a vector of size k\*d), multiplied with a vertical stack of d times the matrix X. Then the dim(range) is d\*rank(X)

Comment: For the others, the mapping is not linear any more (if entries in A and B are your function arguments), so it's going to be more complicated. But probably possible to do. If you reformulate your question a bit, maybe you get an answer by someone then.